# String split on multiple fields to one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the below set as a field for one value:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Colour       |       Amount     |       Size       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  Black,Blue,Green   |       1,2,2      |   100,100,100    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I need to do a string split on each of them and return it in one go.

I've currently got this and works for colour:

```
SELECT value as colour
FROM [table_name] 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(colour, ',')
```

I can't figure out how to do multiple string splits in one go. It should return it as this then:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Colour       |       Amount     |       Size       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Black       |        1         |        100       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Blue        |        2         |        100       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Green       |        2         |        100       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You really need to fix your design here. `STRING_SPLIT`, however, has no idea what ordinal position is. I suggest looking `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `string_split()` doesn't provide the option to preserve the order of the substrings it produces.  Hence, that is very, very tricky to use in this case.

I prefer a recursive CTE (until the function gets fixed):

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as color,
             convert(varchar(max), null) as amount,
             convert(varchar(max), null) as size,
             convert(varchar(max), colors + ',') as rest_colors,
             convert(varchar(max), amounts + ',') as rest_amounts ,
             convert(varchar(max), sizes + ',') as rest_sizes,
             0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select left(rest_colors, charindex(',', rest_colors) - 1),
             left(rest_amounts, charindex(',', rest_amounts) - 1),
             left(rest_sizes, charindex(',', rest_sizes) - 1),
             stuff(rest_colors, 1, charindex(',', rest_colors), ''),
             stuff(rest_amounts, 1, charindex(',', rest_amounts), ''),
             stuff(rest_sizes, 1, charindex(',', rest_sizes), ''),
             lev + 1
       from cte
       where rest_colors <> '' 
     )
select color, amount, size
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f215d5a33b972dab6d318c5bffa2258) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon mentioned, `string_split()` does not GTD sequence.  That said, and if you are open to a Table-Value Function, consider the following where we `UNPIVOT` your data and then apply a final `PIVOT`.   Note:  The `RN = ...` could be replaced with your own ID (if you have one)

I adjusted the values to illustrate there is a proper sequencing.

**Example**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select RN = row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
      ,[Colour]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[Size]
 From YourTable
)
Select *
 From (
        Select RN,Item='Colour',B.* From  cte Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Colour,',') B
        Union All
        Select RN,Item='Amount',B.* From  cte Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Amount,',') B
        Union All
        Select RN,Item='Size'  ,B.* From  cte Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Size  ,',') B
      ) src
 Pivot ( max(RetVal) for Item in ([Colour],[Amount],[Size] ) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
RN  RetSeq  Colour  Amount  Size
1   1       Black   1       100
1   2       Blue    2       200
1   3       Green   3       300
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```